# Errors getting node-oracledb to work with hardened macOS app

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, node-oracledb, code-signing-entitlements

I'm trying to get the [oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb) node package to work with an electron app. It works fine in development, but breaks when I generate a production build. I've traced this down to code signing / hardening process of macOS where the app cannot interact with the oracle drivers that are installed onto the user machine separately from the app. I've tried disabling the various [entitlements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/hardened_runtime) but without much luck. Not sure if it's just not possible.

Seems a similar problem happens with the [odbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc) npm package.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example of your app ?

Comment: If your app is sandboxed then aside from including everything within the .app it's probably not going to be able to interact with anything outside of it's container.